# Two circular images on top of one another

Tags: android

I am having two different circular images with different sizes.I have to place both  in same place where the center point will be same.These two imageviews are in a relative layout.
please help..

Answer (score 1):

When using a relative layout the only option to do that is to center both images in the layout, but if you start adding more elements, such as some text above/below any of the images, the result will not  be as expected.

So my recommendation is to do it programatically. You can define a View and override the onDraw() method. Then you would load the bitmaps by means of two ImageView (or BitmapFactory). Then you paint it to the canvas at the desired location. To find out the center of each image you can use the [Rect class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) that you obtain from the [View method getDrawingRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingRect%28android.graphics.Rect%29) after you apply the layout properties (so the size is calculated),, or by hand (create a Rect with de dimensions of the loaded Bitmap if you use BitmapFactory)

Other alterative is using [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) and define the image positions so they are centered (you need to know the image dimensions before hand).

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to help without your layout XML code. Having said that, the moment you see "one on top of the other", you need to consider `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Framelayout, and set the background for the same with an image and then add images on top with setting layout gravity to left or right or middle.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of creating a new sublayout, you can potentially have the ImageViews align on all sides and set the `scaleType` attribute to something like `center`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle_a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/..." 
    android:scaleType="center"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle_b"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/..." 
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/circle_a"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/circle_a"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/circle_a"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/circle_a"
    android:scaleType="center" />
```

This will give the `circle_b` ImageView actually the same dimensions as `circle_a`, but setting the appropriate scaleType will prevent the image from being stretched or misaligned.

//Edit: ups, I meant to say `center`... corrected.